# My program reads first name then last name in another line, while I need it to read first and last name together

Tags: c++

I'm still a new programmer working on my own.

my program reads line by line.

I have first and last names on a txt file as

Dennis Brown

John Mike

it outputs each name in a line
here is my code

```
cout << " Reading from txt file" << endl;
ifstream file("file.txt");
string content;

while (file >> content) {
    cout << content << ' ';
}
system("pause");
return 0;
```

Comment: _my program reads line by line._ No, it doesn't. It reads term by term (where each term is delimited by a whitespace). To read line by line, consider using `std::getline`.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
You can also try like below,

cout << " Reading from txt file" << endl;

ifstream file("file.txt");

string content;

int i = 0;

while (file >> content) {

    cout << content << ' ';

    i++;

    if (i == 2)

    {cout<<endl;i=0;}

}

system("pause");

return 0;
```